# How to read a binary file using Fortran and save to a text file?

Tags: binary, fortran

I have a binary file with following information:

```
ifile.dat
big_endian sequential, nx=530, ny= 427, t=1, 4 variables
```

I would like to read it with a Fortran program and write to a text file. My trial f90 program is:

bin_read.f90:

```
  INTEGER,PARAMETER :: nx=530, ny=427
  REAL :: v1(nx,ny),v2(nx,ny),v3(nx,ny),v4(nx,ny)

  OPEN(10, file= 'ifile.dat', form = 'unformatted', &
 &access='sequential',convert='big_endian')
  OPEN(11, file= 'ofile.txt', form = 'formatted', &
 &status='unknown')

  DO j = 1, ny
    DO i = 1, nx
      READ(10,*)v1(i,j),v2(i,j),v3(i,j),v4(i,j)
      WRITE(11,1)v1(i,j),v2(i,j),v3(i,j),v4(i,j)
1     FORMAT(4(1X,f8.3))
    ENDDO
  ENDDO

  STOP
  END
```

When I execute it after compilation, I am getting the following message:

```
At line 11 of file bin_read.f90 (unit = 10, file = 'ifile.dat')
Fortran runtime error: Format present for UNFORMATTED data transfer
```

Comment: Hey Kayan. I see you're having difficulty with reading data in Fortran, but there isn't a question listed for readers to answer. As Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, experts are more likely to help you if there's a specific, clear, and concise question to be addressed. What are you having trouble doing? Is something wrong with the code? Is a particular function call confusing? What is your current program doing wrong, and what should it do instead? Add a specific question and you'll likely get a good answer. Best of luck!

Comment: What happened when you tried your program? Any messages?

Comment: @DylanKnowles : I am not able to read the binary file. Can you please help?

Comment: @VladimirF: I have updated my question. Can you help me how to read the binary file in fortran?